# In Android, how can I wait for the layout of one view to be completed before I add another to the same parent layout programmatically?

Tags: android, asynchronous, layout

I have multiple lines of text that I want to add to a LinearLayout. However, I only want to add as many as will fit within the fixed vertical size of the layout.

I'm using `onGlobalLayout` and `getLocalVisibleRect` but I can't figure out a way to get the loop to wait for the layout to finish without the latch waiting forever. (I'm sure I just don't understand how the UI thread works.)

Here's what I'm trying:

```
    final LinearLayout content = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerView));
    final Rect myRect = new Rect();
    TextView lastView = new TextView(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        final TextView valueTV = new TextView(content.getContext());

        final CountDownLatch waitForLayout = new CountDownLatch(1);
        valueTV.setText("hallo hallo this is a really long line that might wrap but might not I'm not really sure what will happen");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(15, 5, 50, 20);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);
        final ViewTreeObserver textViewTreeObserver = valueTV.getViewTreeObserver();
            textViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    //Do your operations here.

                    valueTV.getLocalVisibleRect(myRect);

                    Log.i("New Bottom", String.format("Bottom %d", myRect.bottom));
                    waitForLayout.countDown();
                }
            });


        content.addView(valueTV);
        content.requestLayout();

        try {
            waitForLayout.await();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {

        }
    }
```

I'm more than open to moving anything to a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

You're blocking the completion of `onCreate()`, which means your first view is never laid out, so the `countDown()` call is never executed.

The `OnGlobalLayoutListener` already only runs once the first view is laid out, so move your code into the listener and delete the `CountDownLatch` altogether.

```
textViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // put your view adding here
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't in onCreate(). It's started by a button press. But yes, it is clearly blocking the layout. I just can't get it to layout the programmatically added TextView and wait for that layout to finish so I can see how far down the LinearLayout I am so far.

Comment: @aspro Even if it's not in `onCreate()`, you're still adding a view and then deadlocking your app by calling `waitForLayout.await()`. Just remove the `CountDownLatch` from your code and put whatever code needs the size of the text view into the `OnGlobalLayoutListener`